# Error on index.js while deploying cloud function

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to execute python script using Cloud Function event trigger. My index.js has following code:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});

exports.processFile = function(event, callback) {
  console.log('Processing file: ' + event.data.name);
  callback();
};

module.exports = PythonShell;
```

and package.json has following code:

```
{ 
   "name": "python-shell", 
   "version": "0.4.0", 
   "description": "Run Python scripts from Node.js with simple (but efficient) inter-process communication through stdio", 
   "keywords": [ 
   "python" 
    ], 
   "scripts": { 
    "test": "my_script.py" 
   },
   "dependencies" : {}
}
```

But the function is not getting created. It is showing below error :
ERROR:

```
Deployment failure:
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'python-shell'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Please advise how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command first

```
npm install python-shell
```

Comment: Where to run it ? This command does not work on cloud vm instance.can i run the cloud function on cloud shell ? npm install works on cloud shell

Answer (score 0):

As the error stack trace suggests, you have not specified python-shell in your package.json dependencies. Please add it to your package.json.

To add the required dependency without manually updating your package.json file,

1. `cd` to the folder containing your local package.json
2. `npm install python-shell --save`

When you open your package.json, the dependencies field should specify the module and its [semantic version](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning). This is an example.

```
"dependencies": {
  "python-shell": "^0.4.0"
}
```

There are ways to update the versions in the package.json file thereafter, however, it is not in the scope of this question.

After you have done this, try deploying the function.

Comment: My package.json has code :{
  "name": "python-deep",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "description": "to test python run",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "python my_script.py"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "python"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "python-shell": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {}
} 
I have installed python-shell using "npm install python-shell" and also "npm install python-shell--save". but still getting error :"Error: function crashed.Details:
Cannot find module 'python-deep' " while testing

Comment: python-shell installation gives below (Not sure its being installed successfully or not)  

deepshikha_patel@financelcr:~/deep_function$ npm install python-shell
python-deep@0.4.0 /home/deepshikha_patel/deep_function
└── python-shell@0.4.0
deepshikha_patel@financelcr:~/deep_function$

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Was the first error solved, where the function could not even be deployed?

Comment: By the way, there is no python-deep package on npm.

Comment: I named it as python-deep. Installing python-shell only. Yes deployment is now successful but failing while testing.even i keep it as python-shell,it says "cant find module python-shell "